# Error to pixel manipulation SDL2 c++

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

i'm trying to create a manual color key with pixel manipulation in SDL2, but when i execute the program, the color key doesn't work, these pixels become white, but not transparent.
I tried to Lock the surface and set the surface blendmode, but doesn't work too.

Code:

```
// IO includes
#include <iostream>

// String includes
#include <string>

// SDL includes
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

// Screen constants
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

using namespace std;

// Window variables
SDL_Window *window = NULL;
SDL_Surface *windowSurface = NULL;

// Image surfaces
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *image = NULL;

// Functions
bool initializeSDL();
SDL_Surface *loadSurfaceFromFile(string path);
void SetColorKey(SDL_Surface *surface, Uint32 color);
bool LoadFiles();
void FreeMemory();

// SDL_main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // Try to initialize and load files
    if(initializeSDL() == false){
        FreeMemory();
        return -1;
    }
    if(LoadFiles() == false){
        FreeMemory();
        return -1;
    }

    // Blit images
    SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, windowSurface, new SDL_Rect(70, 277, image->w, image->h));

    // Update screen
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    // Loop
    SDL_Event ev;
    while(true){
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) && ev.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool initializeSDL(){
    // Try to initialize the video
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ){
        // Print error
        cout << "Error to initialize the video: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Try to create the window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Surface", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == NULL){
        // Print error
        cout << "Error to create the window: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Try to initialize PNG format
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    if(! (IMG_Init(imgFlags) &imgFlags) ) return false;

    // Get the window surface
    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    // If everything is fine, return true
    return true;
}

SDL_Surface* loadSurfaceFromFile(string path){
    // Create a temporary surface
    SDL_Surface *tmpSurface = NULL;

    // Create an optimized surface
    SDL_Surface *optimizedSurface = NULL;

    // Try to load the tmpSurface
    tmpSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    if(tmpSurface == NULL){
        // Print error
        cout << "Error to load the image: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    // Try to optimize the surface
    optimizedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(tmpSurface, windowSurface->format, NULL);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface); // Free tmpSurface memory
    delete tmpSurface; // Delete the tmpSurface
    if(optimizedSurface == NULL){
        // Print error
        cout << "Error to optimize the image: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }

    return optimizedSurface;

}

void SetColorKey(SDL_Surface *surface, Uint32 color){
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels;
    int pixelCount = (surface->pitch/4) * surface->h;
    Uint32 transparent = SDL_MapRGBA(image->format, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    for(int i=0;i<pixelCount;i++){
        if(pixels[i] == color){
            pixels[i] = transparent;
        }
    }
}

bool LoadFiles(){
    // Try to load the background
    background = loadSurfaceFromFile("background.bmp");
    if(background == NULL) return false;

    // Try to load the image
    image = loadSurfaceFromFile("image.png");
    if(image == NULL) return false;

    // Set manual color key to image
    SetColorKey(image, SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0, 255, 255));

    return true;
}

void FreeMemory(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Works fine with blend mode set to `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND`. Of course there are other problems, like completely wrong `delete` and unnecessary `new`.